# Propagator in massive QED/Schwinger model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral, fermions, functional-determinants

I'm trying to integrate out the fermions from the path integral in the massive QED/Schwinger model

$S = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^{dx} \left( - \frac{(F_{\mu\nu})^2}{4} + \bar{\psi} \left( i\gamma^\mu D_\mu + m \right) \psi \right) \ ,$

where the covariant derivative is

$D_\mu = \partial_\mu + igA_\mu \quad\Rightarrow\quad i\gamma^\mu D_\mu = i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - g\gamma^\mu A_\mu \ .$

When I integrate out the fermions I keep the gauge field constant

$Z = \int\mathcal{D}A\exp \left[ - \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^{dx} \left( - \frac{(F_{\mu\nu})^2}{4} \right) \right]Z_\psi \ ,$

where

$Z_\psi = \int\mathcal{D}\bar{\psi}\mathcal{D}\psi\exp \left( - \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^{dx} \bar{\psi} \left( i\gamma^\mu D_\mu + m \right) \psi \right) = \det\left( i\gamma^\mu D_\mu + m \right) = \exp\text{tr}\log\left( i\gamma^\mu D_\mu + m \right) $
$= \exp \left( \frac{\text{tr}\log\left[\left( i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - g\gamma^\mu A_\mu + m \right)\left( -i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - g\gamma^\mu A_\mu + m \right)^\dagger\right]}{2} \right) = ... = \exp \left( \frac{\text{tr}\log\left( \partial^2 + i gA_\mu\partial^\mu + g^2A_\mu^2 + m^2 - 2mg\gamma^\mu A_\mu \right)}{2} \right) \ ,$

where I used properties of the gamma function (in Euclidean metric) and

$(i\gamma^\mu D_\mu)^\dagger = -i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu - g\gamma^\mu A_\mu$

The problem with this is that all other terms except the "$\gamma^\mu A_\mu$"-term in $Z_\psi$ are proportional to identity matrices. I initially thought that I could write the fermion propagator as a square root of a scalar propagator, but I'm not able to. Am I doing something wrong?

I have a feeling that there's a sign error in front of the $\gamma^\mu A_\mu$-term in $(i\gamma^\mu D_\mu)^\dagger$, but i don't know how to motivate this.

Comment: How did you add $(i\gamma^\mu D_\mu)^\dagger $ in logarithm?

Comment: I said that $Log(x) = \frac{Log(|x|^2)}{2}$ (up to an overall sign on the imaginary part I don't care about).

Comment: @A.Dunder How did you resolve this issue? I am also stuck with the same.